# How do I get an object from another void c#

Tags: c#, .net, object, uwp, void

I want to change `item.header` from the `Timer_Elapsed` method. How can I acheive it?
This is my code:

```
namespace Oceansurfer
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
        }

        public void TabView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabViewItem item = CreateNewTab(1);
            item.Header = Shared.FileHelper.ReadTitleFromFile();
            (sender as TabView).TabItems.Add(item);
        }
        public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {    
        }
    }
}
```

Please, if you can answer this, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Sorry but it is totally unclear to me what are you trying to do. Could you explain better with some example?

Comment: Are you trying to access a local variable of one method in a different method?

Comment: yes, I am trying to do that. Thanks for the fast reply:)

Comment: you can do it by passing it as an argument to method that will change it

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Would be helpful to see more of your class. I guess the TabView is a member variable of your class. In this method above you add an item to the TabView. So you can access this TabView in another method and access also the item that has been added before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a private member, in this case, all methods of the current class to access this item or you can use the TabItems of TabView to get the latest item. In addition, if you want to change the Header of TabeViewItem in Timer_Elapsed method, since the timer is used with worker threads and the UI needs to be updated in the UI thread, you need to use [Dispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-19041) method to back to the UI thread.

```
private TabViewItem currentItem;

public async void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        //TabViewItem item = Tabs.TabItems[Tabs.TabItems.Count-1] as TabViewItem;
        currentItem.Header = "hello2";
    });

}

private void Tabs_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TabViewItem item = CreateNewTab(1);
    item.Header = Shared.FileHelper.ReadTitleFromFile();
    (sender as TabView).TabItems.Add(item);
    currentItem = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the local variables of one method from within another method. However, there are multiple ways to access the same object in different methods. The procedural way would be to return it as the result of one method and/or pass it as a parameter to another method. The object oriented (and recommended) way is, when the methods are all part of the same class, make a field (or property) for the object you want to access in multiple methods.